# How do I install a new package not part of the standard repository in TeXLive?

Tags: texlive, installing

I'm trying to install the `eqexam` package in windows 8. I followed all the installation instructions as noted in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages. But I still can't include the package eqexam. What am I doing wrong. How are we supposed to install packages not a part of the standard repository manually?

Could someone provide a comprehensive list of steps to properly install a package (using eqexam as an example) not listed in a repository using TexLive?

Comment: Did you run `latex` on `eqexam.ins`, and install the different diles at the relevant places in your `texmf-local` directory?

Comment: @Bernard yes I did. Could you provide a comprehensive list of steps to properly install a package not listed in a repository using TexLive?

Comment: Packages can be made in many ways, so a general guide does not make sense. Do you have a link to that package so we can see what it actually is?

Comment: As far as I can see everything is explained in the eqexam manual on ctan. Remember you also need the acrotex stuff (which is also not available for texlive)

Comment: The simplest would be to download `eqexam.tar.lzma` from MiKTeX repository on CTAN (it is part of MiKTeX), unzip it where you want: you'll obtain a `texmf` directory which contains everything, in TDS architecture.  Just copy everything in this directory at the root of your  `texmf-local`.

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqexam?lang=en is the link to the package I was talking about. So, is there no way for me to use this package?

Comment: It says it is already installed as part of [AeB Pro](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aeb-pro) in MikTeX. So that tells you two things: (i) you may already have the package installed; and (ii) of course you should be able to use the package.